# grep and sed - find function calls in files

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, grep

I need to find usages of class methods in project folder (for refactoring).

Now I'm search with `grep -nr "className." .`. And get list like:

```
file1.js:874:    var x = className.method1() + m;
file5.js:330:    console.log(className.method2());
etc...
```

My goal is to get only methods that used in files without any code around.

For example if we have line in file like:

```
if(className.varIsSetted())
```

In output get only:

```
varIsSetted
```

Also I want to remove duplicates and sort lines, but it's not problem with `sort` and `uniq` at the end of pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below grep command.

```
grep -oPr '\bclassName\.\K\w+(?=\()'
```

`\K` discards the previously matched chars from printing at the final.